# Не могу преобразовать скрипт на TypeScript в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, visual-studio-code

Я пользуюсь VisualStudio Code установил расширение для ts и js, но почему-то не работает команда.

```
PS D:\ts> tsc main.ts
tsc : The term 'tsc' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was include
d, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ tsc main.ts
+ ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (tsc:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Ts and js поддерживается из коробки, вы не то устанавливаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows не видит ваш `tsc`.

#### Установка

```
npm install -g typescript
```

#### Проверка

```
tsc --version

tsc --help
```

Если не заработает - надо найти в какую папку `npm` сохранил `tsc` и прописать в `PATH` операционной системы windows.